# Permission change event in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, event-receivers

I am working on one solution where, I need to track changes over permission for any documents under selected sites. If I do crawl to each document I will ofcourse will get the updated permission, but considering this as time consuming process. I need solution so that, in case any one change permission to file/Document at anytime. I should be notified by any mechanism, so that I could update the permission changes in my record. In this scenario I will be only looking for those document for which actually the permission change has happened.

Please help me if any one knows how to achieve this in sharepoint using C#.net. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of ways you can get it.

1. If you enable the auditing on your site collection then everything will be recorded their (as per ur settings). you have to review the logs file to get the update, but it is manual process. Unless you can automate it.
2. create an event receiver using the [SPSecurityEventReceiver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/jj175805(v=office.15)), here is the details explaination and example of it.http://www.timferro.com/wordpress/archives/737
3. or use 3rd party tools to control it.

Comment: I can't have the farm admin rights on SharePoint server. I believe the Audit logs and Event requires Farm admin rights, I hope I am correct here?

Comment: audit logs a site collection level settings "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-A9920C97-38C0-44F2-8BCB-4CF1E2AE22D2" but for event receiver i am not sure if you can create one at client side